# How do I conventionally create a replica of an element as a new element in HTML using JavaScript (jQuery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b8fr76cb/

I would like to effectively create a new box by clicking on the "New" button in the navigation bar. I have seen recommendations online not to make use of long HTML strings and append the element that way, so, as far as my limited knowledge goes, this rules out creating a customised box from the get-go. I, thus, see two options:

1. Make a replica of the current box (there will always be at least one, since there'll be a default one from the beginning) and adjust the properties as per the individual cases.
2. Have a hidden "skeleton" box that I replicate and then adjust the properties as per the individual cases. However, I'm not sure whether this option is conventional or permitted or ugly or any other adjective.

Please advise as to which of these is the better option or if there is a better, more recommendable option.

Here's the HTML for the box:

```
<ul class="list-group box">
  <li class="list-group-item text-right box-title-area">
    <h4 class="box-name not-selectable">Title</h4>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil rename-box" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item rename-box-controls">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control new-name">
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default confirm-change-name"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default cancel-change-name"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item not-selectable">
    Entry1
    <span class="badge">10</span>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item not-selectable">
    Entry2
    <span class="badge">10</span>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item not-selectable">
    Entry3
    <span class="badge">10</span>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item btn-group buttons" role="group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Button1</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Button2</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Button3</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here's the skeleton code for the JavaScript function that I need to complete:

```
$('#new-box').click(function() {
 /* Code to add new box alongside the last one. */
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [`jQuery.clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) function.

```
var element = $(".myBox").clone();
// Do your modifications to the box here.
$(element).find('.removeThisRow').remove(); // For example remove a row from the box
$(element).appendTo('#myBoxContainer');
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: I made a few changes to my code and eventually found this solution the most convenient. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

working Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/b8fr76cb/1/

you could just use a simple statement to get your requirement.

```
$('#new-box').click(function() {
    $("#first-row").parent().append('<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2">'+$("#first-row").html()+"</div>");
  });
```

Use of `.parent()` to target cloning element and use of `.append()` to create html tags after the available html code.

Comment: Thank you very much! I just have one concern. I will be loading user boxes from a database, so if the user has, say, two boxes at the outset, won't `$("#first-row").html()` result in the duplication of both, ending with a total of four boxes after a single click?

Comment: No, there won't be duplication there, as use of `#id` is estimated as unique through out the document.

Comment: Of course. I was misled by my own bad choice of an ID. I see that I named the first column `#first-row` unintentionally. Thank you for indirectly helping me to notice that! :-)